# Css :not() selector not supporting complex selectors inside it

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

With CSS3 both `:not()` selector as well as `attribute contains selector` are available, but while mixing the both there comes the problem, it is not working.

HTML:

```
<input type='text'/>
<input type='text' id="dasd_Date_asd"/>
```

CSS:

```
input[type='text']:not(input[id*='Date']) {
    display:none;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hp2pcmxm/1/)

Can anyone tell what is going on wrong here?

**Note:** There is no privilege given to us for changing the markup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use two selectors in not:

```css
input[type='text']:not([id*='Date']) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text' />
<input type='text' id="dasd_Date_asd" />
```

Selectors level 3 does not allow anything more than a single [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors) within a :not() pseudo-class.

Comment: You may consider adding that the original code works nowadays without any workaround

Answer (score 4):

You should first select input type and then cutt off the input with type id that has value "Date". your were again providing input as a selector in :not()

try this.

```css
     input[type='text']:not([id*=Date]) {
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
<input type='text'/>
<input type='text' id="dasd_Date_asd"/>
```

Comment: Yeah its working. And how can i say that my selector is invalid.?

Answer (score 4):

As of 2021 your code actually works and you can use complex selectors in `:not()` statements. It works for all major browsers (https://caniuse.com/css-not-sel-list)

https://jsfiddle.net/o6x10ytc/