# Styling a specific type of element except for the last one within a nested structure

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've got the following HTML structure which I'm trying to style using CSS selectors only:

```
<footer>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <nav class="col-md-9"></nav>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Imagine all the columns are stacked in a small viewport. 
I want all columns except for the very last one to apply a margin-bottom to space the columns.

I've tried some different approaches, but to no avail:

```
footer [class^="col-"]:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

footer [class^="col-"]:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
```

First, why do these fail? Second, what's the right approach here?

Comment: `:not` cannot handle complex selectors. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26997609/2813224

Comment: @zer00ne: There aren't any complex selectors in use here. There's just one pseudo-class per :not() here.

Comment: "First, why do these fail?" They *do* work - they're just matching too many elements. Every last column is the last child of its parent row. That's the reason why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use `footer > div.row > *` to apply the margin-bottom 3rem, then use `footer > div:last-child > div:last-child` ( or `footer > div.row:last-child > div:last-child`, won't make a difference)  to reset the last margin to 0:

(note: I only used the `.wrap` div to apply a backgroun in order to make the margins (and the "no-margin" on the last element) visible)

```css
.wrap {
background: #ccc;
}
footer > div.row > * {
margin-bottom: 3rem;
background: #dff;
}
footer > div:last-child > div:last-child {
margin-bottom: 0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<footer>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Content 1</div>
    <nav class="col-md-9">Content 2</nav>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Content 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-9">Content 4</div>
  </div>
</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest styling them all, then removing the margin on the last one, like so:

```
footer [class^="col-"] {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

footer .row:last-child [class^="col-"]:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0; // or however much
}
```

If using `last-of-type`is beneficial in any way, then by all means use that, but it should be equivalent if you're implementing Bootstrap (which your class names suggest).